# How to clone a specific branch from new git Visual Studio 2019 (not from command)?

Tags: git, visual-studio

How to clone a specific branch from git Visual Studio 2019? I know how to do it in command but not sure how to di it using new git in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

All I can do is to clone the master first and choose the specific branch from there.

Comment: Steve - I posted an illustrated method for VS 2019. You stated that you must clone the master and then choose the branch. Likely the method that I've posted. Hope the details help others on their way.  Also, I wonder if coderWorld's solution is GitHub specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be only one route to get a branch via VS. It cannot be done directly but there is a simple path.

1. Get the address of the main branch from the repo. Forget about branches at this point.

[image: Get master address via clone option.]

2. Tell VS that you want to clone an existing repo.

[image: Clone via VS]

3. Give VS the git repo address - it's in the paste buffer so just paste it into the repo location field. Set repo destination. Start clone operation.

[image: Set VS repo info]

4. Observe VS complete operation. (If credentials are already correct.)

[image: VS clone of master is successful.]

5. Switch to desired branch - in this example it's dev.

[image: Switch to desired repo.]

That's it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 14):

While using Git, its advisable to use a CMD or PowerShell instance. Can you try:

```
git clone -b branch_name --single-branch 'repo_url'
```

**branch_name** is the name of your branch, and **repo_url** is the link of your remote repository (repository location).

**If you want to get it done through the UI:**

1. You first need to go to Github
2. From the branches dropdown click on the branch you need. You can view the dropdown here:
   [image]
3. Then copy the Github URL (Copy from the address bar) and paste it in VS studio. That's it.
   [image]

If you click on different branches, the URLs will be different. For example now I selected ***constraints-2-0*** and as you can see the URL at the top has changed.
[image]

Comment: As mentioned, I know how to do it using command but I would like to know how to do it in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Added steps to do it from the UI as well. @Steve

Comment: Please accept the answer if solves your purpose. Ty! :)

Comment: Where is the branch drop down list? Can print screen?

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: When you copy the git url, there are all the same url no matter what branch you choose. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: Ofcourse how else am I getting the screenshots? I added another image to clarify this.

Comment: I mean have you actually copy the git url from your browser and paste it at Visual Studio 2019 to clone the branch? I tried and it doesn't work. All I can do is to clone the master first and choose the specific branch from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225341/discussion-between-coderworld-and-steve).